# Passed JavaScript object to server is null

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

With `DataTables` you should be able to get the column order like this on the server `Request.Form.GetValues(string.Format("order[0][dir]"));` But `order[0]` is null for me. I can see in developer tool it post `object.object` for `order[0]`.

If I make a temp hack and pass `d.order[0].dir`directly and let MVC ModelBinder bind it, it works fine. So `d` *have* the wanted value client-side.

I return `d` by extending it with other data I need(removed in this example). I don't know if that's the problem?

I also tryed returning `d` in a callback but it didn't help for me.

I don't know what else I can do, can someone see something I'm missing or doing wrong?

// documentation: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

Client

```
"ajax": {
    "url": url,
    traditional: true,
    "data": function (d, settings) {
        return $.extend({}, 
                        d,  // d.order[0] is null on server
                        {ascDesc: d.order[0].dir} // temp hack that works
                       );

    },
}
```

Server side is the object null:

```
var order = Request.Form.GetValues(string.Format("order[0][dir]")); // null
```

Comment: Hmm.. It works if I remove `traditional: true`. But I need both, that's a problem :/

Comment: doc: "traditional
Type: Boolean
Set this to true if you wish to use the traditional style of param serialization."

Comment: doc: "Description: Create a serialized representation of an array, a plain object, or a jQuery object suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax request. In case a jQuery object is passed, it should contain input elements with name/value properties."